# How to have All text darker (like bold) in all programs for ease of reading

Tags: windows-10, firefox, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, fonts

HP Pavilion Gaming laptop on Windows 10

I am not asking how to make the display brighter.
I am also not asking how to adjust the contrast between colors.

I need to know how to make a change so All of the text in ALL programs will be darker, i.e., like when I bold text in Word or Outlook.  Then it will be easier for me to read.  I do still want to bold text in programs and have it be even darker.

I have tried High Contrast, but I do not want to set High Contrast, because it makes most things Black.  Printing a screen shot would use an enormous amount of ink.  I usually paste into Word to print them.
Also, when I have High Contrast set, open Kindle, and type characters for a search, the characters I type do not display.  It seems that the characters are being echoed back to the screen in the same color as the background for the search box – black.

Examples of where I need “darker/bolded” text:  Windows Settings, Firefox with some web pages, Windows Explorer, Outlook 2016 list of emails in a folder.

I have googled for this but have not been able to find a suitable answer.  I have also adjusted the angle of my screen on my laptop.
Further research I have done:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-make-all-text-darker-in-win-10im-kinda/e371c38a-110d-4883-a627-f8eef2c98836
I have already tried what I found, but it did not make a difference:
To make text darker (easier to read), follow the steps below:

1. Press Windows key; then type cleartype, and select Adjust ClearType text.
2. Follow the onscreen instruction to on how to do  it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-the-computer-easier-to-see-9ac09d27-b913-66dc-2c57-4a804d650d95
If I make text larger, then less text fits on the screen.  Nothing else in Ease of Access of display is useful either.

I have also looked at this:
Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Make the computer easier to see

And this:  https://www.tenforums.com/customization/71878-how-can-i-make-text-dark-everywhere.html

Comment: Can you make a photo of what you see and post it here? It may be that there is a hardware setting or perhaps even a broken display, but without knowing what you see, it is hard to give a proper answer. Also, it could be viewing angle problem. Does it also happen if you rotate the screen more up or down?

Comment: Change the font and font size in your Operating system. There is no setting other than brightness that changes the contrast or makes things darker. I think the larger font is the best workaround. Otherwise, when the text is problematic, zoom to make it appear larger.

Comment: If you are trying to adjust for significant vision issues, you may find 3rd party software is required to make the significant visual changes that will help you interact with your computer. Windows has a finite set of modifications, and you've already done these, from what I can see.

Comment: I use this but it also makes images etc look darker: lower the gamma of your display (most display adapters have a small app for colour management). Otherwise, Randy Reddig has a tiny app called QuickGamma to set the gamma for most windows: http://www.katsbits.com/files/QuickGamma_0.1.1.zip